# Can I integrate flutter with IBM MFP Studio 8.0

Tags: flutter, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to integrate IBM Mobile First Development, studio 8.0 to my flutter app.I want to know how to achieve this.
Please anyone help me

Comment: As of now MobileFirst does not support flutter SDK. Do a feature request with IBM.

Comment: This is no longer the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. IBM MobileFirst Foundation doesn't support Flutter yet.

You can raise a request for enhancement with IBM, More details [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/help/).

Answer (score 0):

IBM now provides a [Flutter client](https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/mfp-client-flutter) for MobileFirst.

Add this to your package's pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  mobilefoundation: ^8.0.2021020113
```

Comment: hi, is it usable nowadays?

Comment: I haven’t checked the latest version but probably as useable as it needs to be. I’d chat to the IBM team and go with their recommendation.

Comment: Are you use it nowadays?

Comment: No. We're going to remove it altogether.

Comment: why? what is reson? is it useless? and what you think use instead of it? do you know alternative for it?